# What is the reason I get this error using bootgen?

Tags: interrupt, xilinx, zynq-ultrascale+

I'm creating a .bif file that will run in Vitis. I'm trying to follow the examples from this place: https://docs.xilinx.com/r/en-US/ug1400-vitis-embedded/Creating-Boot-Images

This is my **create_bif**.bat-script that I ran for XSDK that worked perfectly fine:

```
@echo off
mkdir sw\boot
if exist sw\bootstuff\output.bif del sw\bootstuff\output.bif
 
echo //arch = zynqmp; split = false; format = mcs           >  sw\boot\output.bif
echo the_ROM_image:                                         >> sw\boot\output.bif
echo {                                                      >> sw\boot\output.bif
echo     [bootloader]%cd%\sw\fsbl\Debug\fsbl.elf            >> sw\boot\output.bif 
echo     %cd%\sw\vivado\block_design_wrapper.bit            >> sw\boot\output.bif
echo     %cd%\sw\MYAPP0\Debug\MYAPP0.elf                    >> sw\boot\output.bif
echo     %cd%\sw\MYAPP1\Debug\MYAPP1.elf                    >> sw\boot\output.bif
echo     %cd%\sw\MYAPP2\Debug\MYAPP2.elf                    >> sw\boot\output.bif
echo }                                                      >> sw\boot\output.bif
@echo on
```

However, when running this line in my .bat-script:

```
CALL ./scripts/create_bif.bat
CALL bootgen -image sw\boot\output.bif -arch zynqmp -o sw\boot\BOOT.mcs -w on
```

I get this error:
[errror output running bootgen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxOJk.png)

Is there something wrong with how I run *bootgen* in Vitis?

Comment: The problem comes from your batch script. %cd% is added to the bit file instead of the proper path to the file. Your %cd% variable is not set.

Comment: This line is run outside of that file:

cd %~dp0 

which changes the directory to script path. Do I need to set the cd variable in another way?

Comment: You have edited your post so I can't remember what the initial error was but for sure you had an incorrect paths in your bif file. I would be good to put the content of the .bif in your post.